# Android: extending PhoneBase?

Tags: android

I know it is possible to use TelephonyManager to get information like: service state, device ID, Sim Operator, etc...
Is it possible to edit some of this information?

Couldn't find .set() functions on Android.com documentation but I've found the [GSMPhone.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/GSMPhone.java) source code which includes functions like .setNumber1Number() (used to set/edit the number?).

I basically want to know if it's possible to edit the phone number located on Sim card (Settings->About->Status->My Phone Number).

Appreciate any answer, even a simple "NO", if it's indeed impossible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to edit some of this information?

Only if you write you own firmware.

> Couldn't find .set() functions on Android.com documentation

That documentation is for the Android SDK, for developing apps that can be distributed via the Android Market and similar venues.

> but I've found the GSMPhone.java source code which includes functions like .setNumber1Number() (used to set/edit the number?).

That is from the Android source code. If you write your own firmware, you can use those methods.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I'll take that as a "NO" :)